# Чем отличается веб-сайт от веб-приложения?

Tags: веб-программирование, терминология

Чем отличается веб-сайт от веб-приложения?

Comment: Вот как видит это IBM - [читать](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/wa-websiteapp/index.html)

Comment: Если в основном бизнес логика на клиенте то веб-приложение, а если на сервере то сайт.

Comment: кто-то проголосовал за переоткрытие. объясняйте тогда, пожалуйста, смысл переоткрытия в комментарии.

Answer (score 2):

Веб-сайт - площадка для размещения всякого, публикуемого в веб. В том числе и веб-приложений, кстати.
Веб-приложение - это программа, которая использует веб для взаимодействия с пользователем и другими программами.

С точки зрения простого пользователя не различимы вообще. Всё, что открывается в браузере, является веб-сайтом. Тот же https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ разве воспринимается как какое-то приложение? Так, сайтик, на котором школьники выполняют домашку по информатике:). Одноклассники, вконтакте и прочие фейсбуки тоже никто не назовёт приложениями. Чтобы там не думала IBM про amazon и audi ([ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/466525/192547)), любой нормальный человек скажет: это сайт.

Но чтобы сдать зачёт, придётся во всём согласится с IBM:)